# Django Can't CSS / customize image

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to center an image and it doesn't work. I cant customize the image at all with my CSS files.

home.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylehome.css' %}">

<div class="testimage">
    <img src="{% static 'images/bottrade.jpg'%}" alt="erar">

</div>
```

stylehome.css

```
.testimage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: maybe first check in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox if it loads your file `.css`. You could also use it to test some CSS values before you put them in file `.css`

Comment: Yes The CSS work for other thing such as Text, background, button etc.. Only doesnt work for the image

Comment: you set CSS for `div`, not directly for `img` and this can make difference. Maybe you need `.testimage img` instead of `.testimage`

Comment: does your image show up at all?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your image nor other code but try this if this helps.

```css
.testimage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylehome.css' %}">

<div class="testimage">
   <center> <img src="{% static 'images/bottrade.jpg'%}" alt="erar"></center>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.... but doesn't work either

Comment: did you try to put !important in it. or try above code. <center>

Answer (score 0):

`img` is an inline tag. You can align it like text or etc. Use `align-text: center;` in `.testimage`

Like this:

```
.testimage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    align-text: center;
}
```

Or you can `flex` like in the answer below or `.testimage img` with styles for an image.

If you don't want to edit your `.css` files you can add `style: align-text: center;` to your HTML tag.